# I have a problem with checkbox and radio buttons in rails

Tags: checkbox, radio-button, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to make an update in a DB using radio buttons or checkbox. If I select the checkbox (or radio button) it does make an update, but when i do not select it, nothing happens.
The checkbox section in the view:

```
Your curriculum is
    "<%= form_for(:public, :url => {:action => 'public',:id=>@listCv.id}) do |f| %>
       <%= f.check_box :public %> Public  <br />    
       <%= submit_tag("Update") %>
   <% end %>"
```

And the update controller is this one:

```
def public
        @cv=Cv.find(params[:id])
        if @cv.update_attributes(params[:public])
```

```
        redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    else
        #render :text=>@cv.id
        render :text=>params[:privacidad] #just rendering to find why it does not make an update
        #redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you use checkbox I assume that `:public` is a boolean.

Try this :

```
def public
        @cv=Cv.find(params[:id])
        public = params[:public]
        public = false if public != true
        if @cv.update_attributes(public)


        redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    else
        #render :text=>@cv.id
        render :text=>params[:privacidad] #just rendering to find why it does not make an update
        #redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanx, i just found the problem. It was indeed related to the boolean values (the problem was my model, because i was validating the presence of public, and i just found it can't be used this way)

Comment: Great. could you please mark the answer as correct, or vote up the answer.